# Primary keys in Postgresql partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a Rails app with a Postgres 11 database. There's a table (`callees`) that needs to be partitioned. Currently, it has an auto-increment column (`id`) as the primary key. The table is referenced from several tables (foreign key), and it also references several other tables. What would be the best approach to partition the table? Some of the options I have considered,

**Option 1**
Partition the table on `created_on`, with partition tables for each month.
This would require me to modify my primary key to include the `created_on` column, and also update all the tables referencing the `callees` table. It will also increase the complexity of my app as I won't be able to simply access a record via the `id`.

Is this a sane approach? Should I try to implement a unique `id` column across all partitions (maybe by setting up sequences and offsets)?

**Option 2**
Partition the table on the `id` column itself. With this, I can continue to keep `id` as my primary key, and some of my code doesn't need to be updated. But then it might get difficult to write queries for reading from the latest partition (which would be straightforward with a date based partition).

---

What are the factors I should consider for making this decision? Are there any obvious pitfalls that I should be wary of, or any best practices that I can follow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need to partition the table? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: The table is massive (over 500GB), and the writes become extremely slow at times (around 50 secs).

Comment: Partitioning can only improve performance if all queries include the partition key in the WHERE clause so that irrelevant partitions can be excluded early when planning a query. Partitioning on ID is very unlikely to give you any performance gain (actually probably the opposite). What kind of queries do you need to tune?

Comment: I can add a where clause for the date, as we work with the latest entries most of the time. Our queries are mainly writes and simple lookups (for which we have multicolumn indices)

Comment: I doubt you'll see a substantial performance improvement then

Comment: Oh. Our guess was that the occasional slowness is due to the size of the table, and partitioning might help. What would be a typical scenario where partitioning would help?

Comment: Writing won't become less if you partition. You should analyze the cause of the slowness.

Comment: Partitioning might help if most all of the writes would go to the newest partition.  Then the indexes on that partition only might fit and stay in RAM, making index maintenance faster.

Comment: How often do you rely on errors or FK actions in order to enforce the fk constraint?  Maybe you could drop them and rely on "it just happens to be true" rather than "the database forces it to be true".

Comment: Do the tables referring to the callees table, have indexes on their foreign key columns?